# I have two scenes but when adding new ui it's adding it to the first scene all the time and never to the new one why is that?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: New Scene]

It's adding the new UI > Panel to the SampleScene under the Canvas I already have there instead adding it to the New Scene scene and creating a new Canvas for the Panel inside on the New Scene.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to click the context menu on the "New Scene" in the Hierarchy window and select "Set Active Scene".

From the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.SetActiveScene.html):

> The active Scene is the Scene which will be used as the target for new
>   GameObjects instantiated by scripts and from what Scene the lighting
>   settings are used. When you add a Scene additively (see
>   LoadSceneMode.Additive), the first Scene is still kept as the active
>   Scene. Use this to switch the active Scene to the Scene you want as
>   the target.

Comment: I tried to set it to be the active scene still not working. But if instead Panel I'm adding a Canvas to the new scene it will add it to the new scene and then I can add a Panel under the Canvas. But adding a Panel directly will add it under the canvas in the first scene. It looks like no matter what UI element then canvas you add it will add it to the first exist Canvas in my case the first scene.  It's like when adding a Panel it's looking for already exist canvas even if it's in the first scene.

Comment: > It's like when adding a Panel it's looking for already exist canvas even if it's in the first scene.
That may be right. But a Panel can't exist without a Canvas so then you'd just have to create the Canvas yourself in the new scene.